# Fetch the hidden value in the jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a input feild and its hidden. Code is as follows

```
<td><input type="hidden" class='some_id' value="<?php echo $some1_name['some1_id'] ?>"><?php echo $some1_name['some1_id'] ?></td>
```

When i want to click a button and i want to fetch that hidden values and my jquery function is as follows.

```
 $(".button").click(function () {
        var stock_id =$(".some_id").val();
      alert(stock_id);
  });
```

The issue is, its not displaying the value. Kindly Help. Thanks

Comment: is the alert working?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/fj09cpp1/). Please provide a way for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: try to make unique ```class``` or ```id``` and alert. It might be conflicting with duplicate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you have an error in your PHP because your PHP statements need to be end with a semi colon ,

try using

```
<td><input type="hidden" class='some_id' value="<?php echo $some1_name['some1_id']; ?>"><?php echo $some1_name['some1_id']; ?></td>
```